# Nginx How to get multiple $args?

Tags: nginx

Fox example I have URL: /test/new/?arg1=1&arg2=2&arg3=3

Also I have nginx rule: `rewrite /test/(.*)/ /handlers/test.php?action=$1&query=$args break;`

But in my handler $_GET['query'] variable contains only `arg1=1`, but I need all query.

What the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive automatically appends the original query string (unless you add a trailing `?`). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

So `/handlers/test.php?action=$1` will contain the arguments `action`, `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` from your example.

The reason `query=$args` does not work as expected is because it expands to:

```
query=arg1=1&arg2=2&arg3=3
```

which looks like three arguments: `query=arg1=1`, `arg2=2`, and `arg3=3`.

Comment: Adding to that, if you truly needed 'query' to contain the entire original query string, you would basically need to url encode to $args, however I am not aware of how you would trigger that in pure nginx. You could do it with some lua, but that is likely overkill here.